# Undefined function error when calling a static constexpr function with CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, static, constexpr, crtp

I'm trying to understand the reason for the compilation error with my CRTP implementation in this example:

```
template<class T>
struct Interface
{
    static constexpr int func();
    static constexpr int func2();
};

template<class T>
struct Default : public Interface<T>
{
    constexpr static int impl_func()
    {

        return 0;
    }

    constexpr static int impl_func2()
    {

        return Default<T>::func() + 2; <----------- (A)
    }
};

struct Derived : public Default<Derived>
{
    static constexpr int impl_func2()
    {
        // NOTE: Using impl_func instead of func here compiles
        return func() + 4; <-------------- (B)
    }
};

struct Derived2 : public Default<Derived2>
{
};

template <typename T> constexpr int Interface<T>::func()
{
    return T::impl_func();
}

template <typename T> constexpr int Interface<T>::func2()
{
    return T::impl_func2();
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int ret = Derived::func2();
    static_assert(ret == 4);

    constexpr int ret2 = Derived2::func2();
    static_assert(ret2 == 2);
}
```

Specifically why is (A) ok while (B) gives me this error:

```
test3.cpp:45:19: error: constexpr variable 'ret' must be initialized by a constant expression
    constexpr int ret = Derived::func2();
                  ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test3.cpp:29:16: note: undefined function 'func' cannot be used in a constant expression
        return func() + 4;
```

Replacing (B) with `return impl_func() + 4` compiles successfully. But neither `Derived::func()` nor `Default<Derived>::func()` work. If (B) needs to be `impl_func()` then is there something different about the fact that (A) is in a templated class that allows it to compile successfully?

Answer (score 1):

With `constexpr` function, **definition** should be available when used...

reordering function definition solve the issue:

```
template<class T>
struct Interface
{
    static constexpr int func();
    static constexpr int func2();
};

template <typename T> constexpr int Interface<T>::func()
{
    return T::impl_func();
}

template <typename T> constexpr int Interface<T>::func2()
{
    return T::impl_func2();
}

// Remaining code.
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rMnna5anj)

Comment: The definition isn't available at (A) either though, but that seems to work fine. Is there something special about (A) being inside a templated class?